# Trying to translate signature and stamp for Chinese print (Characters identified: 戊午九月石年)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, history

Trying to find the origin of this print and the translation of the signature and seal.

[image: signature and feel of Chinese print]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: If there are more inscriptions, you should provide them as well for context. For example, the first two characters 戊午 can mean 1978, 1918, 1858, 1798, and so on.

Comment: 石年 sounds very wired, even Chinese don't know what it means.  We don't speak like that.

Comment: @Siwei 石年 is the name of the painter or writer,  as seen in the seal.

Comment: @joehua You are right! Yes, cong the context and the seal, 石年is the name of the author.  I

Answer (score 1):

This is the work of 宋石年 (1850-1914). 宋 is his family name.

So, the year 戊午 can only be 1858.

BTW, judging by the signature, this artwork was finished when he was 8. To be honest, I can't believe this until I saw [another amazing artwork](http://www.zihuazhijia.com/product/view/pm2016061310013528.html) of him, which was finished when he was 11 ...